# I am trying map right to end in my .obsidian.vimrc

Tags: vim, obsidian

I am trying to remap right in normal mode in my .obsidian.vimrc to jump to the end of a line.

**Things I have tried**

```
 nmap <RIGHT> <END>
```

I did not use $ as I wanted it to jump to the end of the visual line, not the actual line.

I am sure my Vimrc is being read as other more basic mappings are working.

Comment: Try `vmap` instead.